# Testing environment server with SSL

Tags: svn, ssl, project-management

I have the testing server, that hold the Subversion repository, Redmine for PM and of course - it is my testing enviroment.

The problem is that I want to have all my connections encrypted with SSL. When create the SSL manually, whole bunch of problems are coming up: Redmine doesn't trust the cert, my production server cannot update its working copy without prompting for cert acceptance (which I cant answer because I do not have access to console on the hosted server), every time I checkout testing app (webApp) I need to aprove the untrusted cert (Google Chrome), today my cert expired crushing redmine, which I can't get back on track with new cert... the list of problems goes on.

Therefore, **my question is this**: is it possible to have my own SSL cert without, at least most of the above problems? Buying one isn't really the solution, because it is "unnecessary expense" if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SVN you can use the following command:

```
svn up --trust-server-cert --non-interactive
```

I do not know for sure hot to get it into RedMine, however I used always the **file://-URL** as my redmine and SVN are located on same server(which is also faster and does not need any authorisation).

This switch is only available in SVN 1.6.
You can also (self-)sign your certificate and add the signed certificate in subversion's server configuration file:

```
ssl-authority-files = /path/to/cert-file
```

Comment: svn --trust-server-cert - isn't this available only on SVN 1.6?

Comment: Thats too bad. I have SVN 1.5 (Lenny).